# Tableau hyper_0 process fails with result code 7

Tags: linux

Our Tableau on a linux docker image entered a degraded state. When I ran `tsm status -v` I got the following:

```
node1: localhost
        Status: DEGRADED
        'Tableau Server Gateway 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Application Server 0' is in an error state.
        'Tableau Server Interactive Microservice Container 0' is running.
                'MessageBus Microservice 0' is running.
                'Relationship Query Microservice 0' is running.
                'Credentials Service 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server VizQL Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Cache Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Coordination Service 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Cluster Controller 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Search And Browse 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Backgrounder 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Non-Interactive Microservice Container 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Data Server 0' is running.
        'Tableau Server Data Engine 0' is in an error state.
                'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Command Line operation failed to execute
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed run command '[/usr/bin/supervisorctl, -c, /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/supervisord/supervisord.conf, start, hyper_0]', result code 7.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Command Line operation failed to execute
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed run command '[/usr/bin/supervisorctl, -c, /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/supervisord/supervisord.conf, start, hyper_0]', result code 7.'
```

In the `stdout_hyper_0.log` log file I saw "Permissions for 'ssl_key' have to be 0600"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of your key file to be 0600. For example, in my case my file somehow had permissions 0660, so I changed it to 0600 via `chmod 0600 /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/config/hyper_0.20221.22.0415.1144/hyperSecurity/hyper.root.key`.